# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for physics body contact

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, forced-unwrapping

I can't seem to figure out which optional value it is talking about or why i am getting this error. I checked my score integer and made sure that I declared its value is 0 until it makes contact with the enemy. In the simulator the counter counts the first 4 or 5 enemies then crashes.

```
var score = Int? ()
var scoreLabel = UILabel ()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
scoreLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 
20))
scoreLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()

score = nil
if score == nil {
    score = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
}
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

let firstBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
let secondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet) &&  
(secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) ||
(firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.enemy) && 
(secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.bullet)) {
 //i get the error next line            
collisionWithBullet((firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode), 
bullet: (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode))
 }
}

func collisionWithBullet(enemy: SKSpriteNode, bullet: SKSpriteNode){

score? += 1
scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
enemy.removeFromParent ()
bullet.removeFromParent ()

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change score to

```
var score = 0
```

instead of

```
var score = Int? ()
```

and instead of this part

```
score = nil
if score == nil {
    score = 0
    scoreLabel.text = "\(score!)"
}
```

write only this

```
scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
```

Edit:
instead of this part

```
collisionWithBullet((firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode), 
bullet: (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode))
```

do something like this

```
if let firstNode = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
 secondNode = secondBody .node as? SKSpriteNode {
collisionWithBullet((firstNode), 
    bullet: (secondNode))
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help! i thought your advice worked and i almost cried tears of joy but it just took longer than usual to crash, it made it to 9 enemies then it crashed same problem same line. :(

Comment: it doesn't crash as soon though so thats kind of weird it doesn't crash until around 10 or so @roee84

Comment: No problem. Where it's crashing now?

Comment: the same line and the same error, I don't think there is a problem wth my score, because i just //'d out my "score += 1
scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"" defined in my collision with bullet method and i am still getting the error on the collisionWithBullet((firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode), 
bullet: (secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)) line. I think it is because of my "as!" statement but i can't think of an alternative solution

Comment: it worked! i made it to 97 just to make absolutely sure! you're a rockstar. ill vote up your answer on my other account. didn't want to ask this on my OG account because i knew people would down vote this question haha @roee84

Comment: Glad to help :) and please mark as the correct answer